# Creating a calculator

Tags: magento2

I need to re-create a calculator page as per the one on link here, https://www.theramppeople.co.uk/ramp-length-calculator/, this would be to our french shop that is why we can't use the same link as above, I have created the page https://www.rampes-directes.fr/calculatrice-de-longueur, but the results are not being displayed, for the moment this has being only worked out on the admin panel, I have basically used the content from the English "page" and translated to French.

On the result "text" we have this :

```
<div id="rampCalcResults">
<div class="results" style="display: none;">
<p><strong>Longueur de Rampe Requise:</strong><br /><span id="ResultsInFeet">?</span> feet (<span id="ResultsInMm">?</span> mm)</p>
```

Anyone know where do I get the results from ?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I can see is with your jQuery code is not loaded properly.

You have a working JQuery Code in your English version.
[image: Screenshot of jQuery onchange handle]

But the same is not available in your **fr** version. As there is no onclick event handler you wont get the result.

Please check your console. The `fr` version is having 3 console errors. Make sure you never ignore console errors even though if it is not related to your issue it may impact you JS execution. **So it is always a good practice to keep your code console clean**.

Hope it finds helpful.

Comment: Abdul Pathan many thanks for your help, this was very helpfull :)

Comment: Most Welcome, if it helped please upvote & approve the answer so that this will be helpful for others as well.